# How to get the function name from function pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, function-pointers

I have a function which takes a function pointer

like

```
public void myfunc<a,b>(Func<a,b> functionpointer)
{
  String functionname;
  // Do some magic to get functionpointers name and set it to functionname
 }
```

Is it possible to get the function's name without running it?

I know that you can get the function name of the currently running function, but how do you get the name of a function that you're going to call?

Forgive me if such a question might have been posted before, i can't find a solution for it in C#

Comment: Note that "anonymous" functions might give useful information. Does it help to know the function "name" for a call like `myfunc(x => x.Blah)`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [MemberInfo.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx)

```
string functionname = functionpointer.Method.Name;
```

Comment: In terms of performance , how big of a hit would this be? Is it heavy?

Comment: @BrijeshBharadwaj, its a property of the function `Func`. Its not going to be heavy at all, I believe. Even if there is a performance effect on accessing the getter it would be negligible.

Comment: @BrijeshBharadwaj I think the first question should be, does this return really the name you want or a random name generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void myfunc<a, b>(Expression<Func<a, b>> expr)
{
    Func<a, b> functionpointer = expr.Compile();

    String functionname = "";
    var mce = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if(mce!=null)
    {
        functionname = mce.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection

```
 foreach (Type objType in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    //List<string> listInner = new List<string>();
                    var listInner = new HashSet<string>();
                    listInner.Add(objType.FullName);
                    foreach (MemberInfo obMember in objType.GetMembers())
                    {
                        listInner.Add(obMember.MemberType + " " + obMember.ToString());

                    }
                 }
```